# Spring Batch OOM error

Tags: out-of-memory, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch framework for reading the huge file using Partitioner framework. The sample code is attached.

If the file records are going more than 1000 then I am getting Outofmemory error due to ConcurrentHashMap handling in execution context.

```
 public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    System.out.println("inside Partition" +inboundDir);
   // Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    File file = new File(inboundDir);
    System.out.println("is directory"+file.isDirectory());
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> queue = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                List<List<String>> trunks = new ArrayList<>();
                System.out.println("Inside File"+file);
                // read and store data to a list of trunk
                int chunkSize = 1;
                int count = 1;
                int totalCount=0;
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                    String line;
                    List items = new ArrayList();
                    System.out.println("chunkSize"+chunkSize);
                    System.out.println("count"+count);

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        totalCount=totalCount+1;
                        System.out.println("line---------"+count % chunkSize);
                        if (count % chunkSize == 0) {
                            trunks.add(items);
                            items = new ArrayList();
                            System.out.println("trunks---------"+trunks.size());

                        }
                        System.out.println("items---------"+line);
                        items.add(line);
                        count++;
                        System.out.println("count---------"+count);


                    }
                    if(items.size()>0){
                        trunks.add(items);

                    }
                    System.out.println("inside total count"+totalCount);

                    for (int i=2; i<trunks.size(); i++) {
                        ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
                        value.put("fileResource", trunks.get(i));
                        value.put("totalCount", totalCount);
                        queue.put("trunk"+i+file, value);
                    }


                }catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    return queue;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the items to the `ExecutionContext`?  That isn't what partitioning or the `ExecutionContext` is for.  What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am new to the spring batch. I wanted to read the file and give each record to each thread to process. Kindly help.

Comment: If you want a partition per file, just us the `MultiResourcePartitioner` provided by Spring Batch: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/MultiResourcePartitioner.html

Comment: I want to split the single file records to different threads. I don't want to give one file to one context

Comment: Then you'd need to use something like remote chunking or split the files up.

Comment: hi I cant split the file. If I transfer the file from partitioner to slave then it is working. but if i read the file at the master level and giving records as chunk (500) to slaves it is not working. Throwing out of memory. the processing file size is 12MB.

Comment: Reading at the master and processing at the worker is remote chunking, not remote partitioning.  There are mechanisms for that as well in Spring Batch.

Comment: Thanks Michael Minella .. I have done changes by sending metadata from master and actual data read by slaves.

Comment: But during job completion i am getting the following error. Kindly Help.. I am using Spring batch version 2.2.0

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not deserialize object: eof=true at length=0
 at org.springframework.batch.support.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:71)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao.copy(MapJobExecutionDao.java:50)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao.updateJobExecution(MapJobExecutionDao.java:104)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:160)